# Concatenating and iterating through multiple Cells VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to iterate through data (simular to that shown below) that is stored in different cells and combine them into a single cell seperated by a new line (chr(10)). **The amount of data that needs to be imported into one cell will change.**

```
2991
19391
423
435
436
```

The code needs to iterate through the whole sheet regardless of any line breaks. The required format is:

```
    2991 - all three cells would be combined into one cell in the next column to this one.
    19391
    423
-Line space, this will need to be taken into account and is the seperator of data.
    26991 - all four cells would be combined into one cell in the next column to this one.
    19331
    424
    6764
```

Below is what I have got so far, it takes the column to the left of the current row and combines it, which is wrong.

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

   Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.

      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & chr(10) & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can achieve the above with this code

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1

        Dim strBuilder As String
        Set c = Range("A" & i)

        If Not IsEmpty(c) And i <> 1 Then
            strBuilder = c & Chr(10) & strBuilder
        ElseIf i = 1 Then
            strBuilder = c & Chr(10) & strBuilder
            c.Offset(0, 1) = Left(strBuilder, Len(strBuilder) - 1)
            strBuilder = vbNullString
        Else
            c.Offset(1, 1) = Left(strBuilder, Len(strBuilder) - 1)
            strBuilder = vbNullString
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be done using a UDF.

Something like

```
Public Function JoinValues(rng As Range) As String

Dim cell As Range
Dim str As String

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
        str = str & cell.Value & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next cell

If Len(str) > 1 Then JoinValues = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)

End Function
```

Then usage would be `=JoinValues(A1:A10)` in a cell to join values. You would also have to change cell formatting in the target cell to allow wrapping text for this to work properly.

---

Assuming your values start in cell A2 enter

```
=IF(A1="",joinvalues(OFFSET(A2,0,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(A2:A10000),0,0),0)-1)),"")
```

in B2 and drag the function down.

Comment: @mehow I agree, it's defiantly not as neat as doing it purely in code. I did however add a method of using it without having to redefine the ranges in each cell..

Comment: still, that produces an output as 299119391423 which is not what the op is looking for

Comment: @mehow you need to wrap text in cell formatting for the chr(10) to take effect.

Comment: Works great, only reason it didn't get top answer is because @mehow answered first!